# How to use multiple checkboxgroups on a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 4 Checkboxes, and they all react like one group as default.

How do I make two "groups", where group1 contain CB1 and CB2 and group2 contain CB3 and CB4, where the groups are independen.

I've tryed with groupboxes and changing the Tag, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different containers for each group. For example you can put 2 `Panel` controls to group it. Put first 2 `Checkboxes` to the first one, and other to the second one.

You can use any other container controls: `Panel`, `GroupBox`, etc..